# How can I get pointRadius() updated on geoChoroplethChart redraw?

Tags: dc.js

On a `dc.geoChoroplethChart`, I'm setting the radius of geojson points using the `pointRadius` method of the path:

```
.geoPath().pointRadius(function(feature, index) {
    var v = placeGroup.all().filter(function(item) { return item.key === feature.id; })[0].value;
    return (v == 0)? 0 : pointScale(v);
});
```

I'm finding that it works well, but on `redraw()` the sizes of the points are not adjusted.  They are adjusted on a `render()`.  How do I get them to be adjusted with a `redraw()` as well?

---

Here's the full chunk of code for the geo chart, in case it's relevant

```
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .scale(1)
        .translate([0, 0]);
    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);
    var width = 280,
        height = 200,
        b = path.bounds(places),  // [[left, top], [right, bottom]]
        x_extent = Math.abs(b[1][0] - b[0][0]),
        y_extent = Math.abs(b[1][1] - b[0][1]),
        s = (.95 / Math.max(x_extent / width, y_extent / height)),
        t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];

    // Update projection with our actual data
    projection
        .scale(s)
        .translate(t)
    ;

    var mapchart = dc.geoChoroplethChart("#map-chart");
    var valueDomain = [0, placeGroup.top(1)[0].value];
    var maxPointRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 40,
        minPointRadius = maxPointRadius / 2;

    var pointScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain(valueDomain)
            .range([minPointRadius, maxPointRadius]);

    mapchart.width(width)
        .height(height)
        .projection(projection)
        .dimension(placeDim)
        .group(placeGroup)
        .colors(d3.scale.quantize().range(['#feb24c','#fd8d3c','#fc4e2a','#e31a1c','#bd0026'])) //first three '#ffffcc','#ffeda0', '#fed976', last one,'#800026'
        .colorDomain(valueDomain)
        .colorCalculator(function (d) { return d ? mapchart.colors()(d) : '#ccc'; })
        .overlayGeoJson(places.features, "placeLayer", function (d) {
            return d.id;
        }).geoPath().pointRadius(function(feature, index) {
            var v = placeGroup.all().filter(function(item) { return item.key === feature.id; })[0].value;
            return (v == 0)? 0 : pointScale(v);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the geoChoroplethChart won't redraw the geojson unless the projection has changed. (It isn't expecting you to change the geoPath - as stated in the documentation, that's mostly a convenience method for reading and determining the center.)

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/geo-choropleth-chart.js#L169-L171

As a workaround, I'd suggest forcing a redraw by resetting the projection each time the chart redraws. Something like:

```
mapchart.on('preRedraw', function() {
    mapchart.projection(projection);
});
```

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#basemixinon--basemixin

Comment: Good stuff; does the trick.  No pretty transitions, but I can live without it.

Comment: I don't think people have considered transitions there because the map itself usually doesn't change and transitioning between projections is pretty esoteric. I'd be open to the change but I'd want to verify that it doesn't cause weird effects when zooming.